# Features not reverting field instances, only field bases

Tags: entities, features

I'm having issues with the latest version of Features. I'm trying to revert a content type but it's not reverting the field instances.

The Content type is created and I can see the field tables in the database. The field_config table contains the fields but the field_config_instance table is empty.

Everything works well if I drop a dev dump of my field_config_instance table into the database I'm reverting to. There are no errors shown or anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: In features issue queue there is a lot of issues about revert failing in many ways. I'm afraid your problem is a matter for one more issue there.

Comment: I'm going to leave this open in case anybody can shed light on it, then close it if it really does look like a Features bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with the latest features.

The solution for me was to run the field_cron. It purges some staff and after that I was able to revert the feature with the field_instances and this time the revert worked and the field was added to the entity.

Hope that could help anybody with similar problem.